# How to add a folder entry to right-hand-side of start menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

I would like to know whether on Windows 7 it is possible to add a folder (e.g. the Downloads folder) just beneath some other entry below the logged-in user's name (John as in the below image):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a new item, but you can rename the Documents, Images and Music folders and then change their library settings to include your download folder.

Alternatively you can drag your downloads folder to the top left of the start menu, and pin it there.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your answer. If I rename an entry on the right-hand-side of the start menu, then it renames the folder. If I change 'Games' to 'Downloads', the folder is renamed, but I would like to rename the menu entry so that it points to a different folder without renaming any filesystem folders. How can I accomplish this (besides creating an entry on the left-hand-sid of the start menu)?

Comment: After renaming it, right click and choose properties. Then add the new downloads to that library, and remove the other ones.

Comment: No matter if renamed or what, when I right click any entry in the right-hand-side of the start menu, the only available entries are `Open` and `Rename`. There is no `Properies`. Where do you mean?

Comment: Ah, in my solution I didn't mention Games on purpose. Games is the only one where it doesn't work. It works with the other 3.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work with Games. Seems really odd to me, especially since I've never played any of them in all these years and would be happy to get rid of that folder (it's the least useful). Anyways, I renamed Music, and it works. Thanks.